# Need to pass multiple Csv files in Jmeter http request

Tags: jmeter

How can I pass multiple CSV files from a local folder, in an Http post request? I want to pick unique files each time.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option would be going for [Directory Listing Config plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md)

Given you point it to the folder where your CSV files live each thread (virtual user) will pick the next file on each iteration.

Directory Listing Config can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)